# SQL Query filter on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this columns :

```
id | partner_id | product_id
-----------------------------
1  |   2        |   71
2  |   2        |   83
3  |   3        |   71
4  |   4        |   83
5  |   4        |   71
6  |   5        |   22
7  |   4        |   55
```

I want only the lines where the partner_id have the product_id 83 AND 71
like this :

```
id | partner_id | product_id
-----------------------------
1  |   2        |   71
2  |   2        |   83
4  |   4        |   83
5  |   4        |   71
```

Thank your very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.product_id in (71, 83) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.partner_id = t.partner_id and
                    t2.product_id in (71, 83) and
                    t2.product_id <> t.product_id
             );
```

However, it might make sense also if you only wanted the partners.  In that case, you can use `group by`:

```
select partner_id
from t
where product_id in (71, 83)
group by partner_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- assuming no duplicates
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tableName where product_id = 71 or product_id = 83
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Also, too bad the downvoters didn't explain what was wrong with your answer (other than the lack of an explanation), since this looks like a working solution to me. +1